# How to access getter() in CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch{}?

Tags: kotlin, scope, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Backendcall

```
val temperature = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
    WebService
        .getTemperatureAsFloat()
        .subscribe()
}
```

But temperature is of type `Job`, since observable on right side is wrapped by `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch{}` .

How can I put the result of this Observables Webservice call `getTemperatureAsFloat()` into temperature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `runBlocking` but it is not recommended.

The recommended approach is to obtain the value where you need it and make that `suspend`.

```
suspend fun getTemperature() = WebService
        .getTemperatureAsFloat()
        .subscribe()
```

And then you call it where you need it.

View Model:

```
fun updateTemperature() = viewModelScope.launch {
    val temperature = source.getTemperature()
    //update a livedata or a flow here
}
```

Fragment:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val temperature = source.getTemperature()
    //do something with your binding here
}
```